# Trying to perform a case_when function inside a mutate verb in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Trying to create a new column based off of an old column, so a basic case_when statement works for me in sql but I'd like to utilize this similar case_when in R when piping through a mutate verb, any help as how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

```
WHEN [Salary Grade] = "C01"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "F03"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "P02"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "TS1"
THEN "1"
WHEN [Salary Grade] = "C02"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "F04"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "P03"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "TS2"
THEN "2"
WHEN [Salary Grade] = "C03"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "F05"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "P04"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "T04"
THEN "3"
WHEN [Salary Grade] = "C04"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "F06"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "P05"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "T05"
THEN "4"
WHEN [Salary Grade] = "C05"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "F07"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "S10"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "T06"
THEN "5"
WHEN [Salary Grade] = "C06"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "F08"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "PM4"
THEN "6"
WHEN [Salary Grade] = "C07"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "F09"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "PM3"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "T07"
THEN "7"
WHEN [Salary Grade] = "C08"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "F10"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "PM2"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "S15"
THEN "8"
WHEN [Salary Grade] = "C09"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "DIM"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "PM1"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "S30"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "T09"
THEN "9"
WHEN [Salary Grade] = "C10"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "S40"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "T10"
THEN "10"
WHEN [Salary Grade] = "C11"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "PDM"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "SMG"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "T11"
THEN "11"
WHEN [Salary Grade] = "C12"
OR  [Salary Grade] = "T12"
THEN "12"
ELSE "Historical"
END
```

Comment: Maybe it might be better to use a lookup(a `*join`?) instead? Many `case_when` calls seem inefficient in my opinion.

Comment: @NelsonGon, that would be my ideal method but there's no table that exist that I could join to, and I thought creating the table and then joining would be just as much work.

Comment: I think creating the table will be better in the long run since  you can always just manipulate that instead of writing so many case_when statements

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with your first 3 case types.  Note that the `TRUE ~ "Historical")` is equivalent to your `ELSE`.

```
library(dplyr)
Salary_Grade <- c("C01","F03","P02","TS1","C02","F04","P03","TS2","C03","F05","P04","T04")
df <- data.frame(Salary_Grade, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df %>% 
  mutate(value = case_when(Salary_Grade %in% c("C01","F03","P02","TS1") ~ "1",
                           Salary_Grade %in% c("C02","F04","P03","TS2") ~ "2",
                           Salary_Grade %in% c("C03","F05","P04","T04") ~ "3",
                           TRUE ~ "Historical"))

   Salary_Grade value
1           C01     1
2           F03     1
3           P02     1
4           TS1     1
5           C02     2
6           F04     2
7           P03     2
8           TS2     2
9           C03     3
10          F05     3
11          P04     3
12          T04     3
```

Answer (score 0):

use of case when will not be the optimal way but if you really want it:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    SalaryBin=case_when(
      Salary_Grade %in% c("C01","F03","P02","TS1") ~ "1",
      Salary_Grade %in% c("C02","F04","P03","TS2") ~ "2",
      # similarly put other conditions 

      TRUE ~ "Historical"))
```